# Don't Understand Para Usage Guidelines

Tags: preposiciones

Listed below are the Para usage rules that I have learned. However, I can't figure out how the following sentence fits into the rules or if the list needs to be added to or clarified.

---

The Usage Rules I've Been Given:

1. Purpose: Necesito una caja para mis cosas.
2. Destination: Salgo para Chile mañana.
3. Deadlines: Tengo que terminar esto para las ocho.
4. Recipients: El regalo es para mi padre.

---

A sentence I'm having trouble with:

> Soy bastante mayor para tomar mis propias decisiones.

The sentence clearly doesn't deal with a recipient, deadline, or destination. Lastly, one doesn't age with a goal in mind.

Comment: A mnemonic I was given is PRODDS: 
PURPOSE
* Used to indicate a purpose or a goal.
* Translation: in order to
RECIPIENT
* Used to indicate the recipient of an action or thing.
* Translation: for
OPINION
* Used to talk about an opinion.
* Translation: for, according to
DESTINATION
* Used to indicate the destination or end point of an object or person.
* Translation: for
DEADLINE
* Used to indicate when something is due or scheduled.
* Translations: for, by, on
STANDARD
* Used to compare something or someone to a standard, such as cheapness or speed.
* Translation: for

Answer (score 4):

In the definition of "para" in the [dictionary of the Royal Spanish Academy](https://dle.rae.es/para) there are 10 meanings listed.

The sentence "Soy bastante mayor para tomar mis propias decisiones" matches meanings 6 and 7:

> 6. prep. Denota la relación de una cosa con otra, o lo que es propio o le toca respecto de sí misma. Poco lo alaban para lo que merece.
> 7. prep. Denota la aptitud y capacidad de una persona. Antonio es para todo, para mucho, para nada.

"Para" in this sentence indicates a relation between age and the ability to take decisions (meaning number 6).  It can also be interpreted according to meaning number 7(ability).

Regarding this sentence it would be more common to say: "Soy ***lo*** bastante mayor ***como*** para tomar mis propias decisiones" (Adding "lo" and "como"). The translation of the sentence in English is: "I'm old enough to make my own decisions".

It is also usual to use a similar construction to indicate a contradictory situation: "Es bastante mayor como para seguir comportándose de ese modo". In this case the meaning matches meaning 6 but the idea is that the person is too old to behave like this.

Below is the full article for "para" in the [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/para):

> para
>
> Del ant. pora.
>
> 1. prep. Denota el fin o término a que se encamina una acción.
> 2. prep. hacia (‖ denota sentido de un movimiento).
> 3. prep. U. para indicar el lugar o tiempo a que se difiere o determina el ejecutar algo o finalizarlo. Pagará para San Juan.
> 4. prep. U. para determinar el uso que conviene o puede darse a algo. Esto es bueno para las mangas del vestido.
> 5. prep. U. como partícula adversativa, significando el estado en que se halla actualmente algo, contraponiéndolo a lo que se quiere aplicar
>    o se dice de ello. Con buena calma te vienes para la prisa que yo
>    tengo.
> 6. prep. Denota la relación de una cosa con otra, o lo que es propio o le toca respecto de sí misma. Poco lo alaban para lo que merece.
> 7. prep. Denota la aptitud y capacidad de una persona. Antonio es para todo, para mucho, para nada.
> 8. prep. Junto con verbo, significa la resolución, disposición o aptitud de hacer lo que el verbo denota, o la proximidad o inmediación
>    a hacerlo, y en este último sentido se une al verbo estar. Estoy para
>    marchar de un momento a otro. Estuve para responderle una fresca.
> 9. prep. Con los pronombres personales mí, sí, etc., y con algunos verbos, denota la particularidad de la persona, o que la acción de lo
>    expresado por el verbo es interior, secreta y no se comunica a otro.
>    Para sí hace; leer para sí; para mí tengo.
> 10. prep. Junto con algunos nombres, se usa supliendo el verbo comprar o con el sentido de 'entregar a', 'obsequiar a', etc. Dar para fruta.
>     Estos libros son para los amigos.

Comment: Thank you for that link. Do you know of a page that goes through all those different cases in a more instructional manner? I've only encountered articles and chapters on por and para that include the limited list I described.

Comment: @Walrath21 Here is one link: http://roble.pntic.mec.es/~acid0002/index_archivos/Gramatica/preposiciones_por_para.htm. Not all cases are explained but the case of "Soy bastante mayor para tomar mis propias decisiones" matches one of the usages explained in the article: "comparación" (comparison).  In this other link: https://www.españolextranjeros.com/2015/05/b2-por-para-uso-y-ejemplos.html it is mentioned the case of the contradictions, called "Contraposición" in the article.

Comment: "Lo bastante" is an adverbial locution that modifies the adjective "mayor", and it can be used with or without "lo" with intransitive verbs. "Lo" tends to be used along with the idea of a particular purpose(=verb+lo+adv+enough+...+to/for/that+pronoun//verb+so much+....to//too much of a+..+to, etc). 
https://grupovaughan.com/a/suficientemente-en-ingles-enough-con-adjetivos/